# gunicorn Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I am hoping someone can help. I have been trying to launch my flask app on ubuntu. The app runs on dev mode, but when I try to run it with gunicorn, I get the following error:

```
[2022-07-24 21:55:44 +0000] [3710] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-24 21:55:44 +0000] [3710] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3710)
[2022-07-24 21:55:44 +0000] [3710] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-24 21:55:44 +0000] [3711] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3711
Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'.
[2022-07-24 21:55:44 +0000] [3711] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3711)
[2022-07-24 21:55:44 +0000] [3710] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-07-24 21:55:44 +0000] [3710] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.


Here is my app.py file
from website import create_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here the site structure.

Website

- script
- static
  -templates
  -apy.py
  -auth.py
  -db
  -models
  -views
  -**innit**.py
  app.py

Can someone help?

Thanks

S

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Had to move the app=create_app above the 'if' statement.